# Script to download images from Reddit

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit

I wrote this script to download images from Reddit. I would like to hear from others on how can I improve this script.

```
import requests as _requests
import os as _os

class Redpy:

    def __init__(self, user):
        """Enter a user agent"""
        print("hello")
        self.user = user

    def download(self, subreddit, number=5, sort_option=None):
        """Downloads images from subreddit.
            subreddit="Name of subreddit"
            number=Number of images to be downloaded
            sort_option=new/hot/top
        """
        subreddit.strip('/')
        if sort_option == None:
            sort_option = ''

        self.url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + subreddit + '/'+  sort_option  +  '.json'

        self.user = {'user-agent':self.user}
        res = _requests.get(self.url, headers=self.user)

        if res.status_code != 200:
            print("Could not download")
            print(res.status_code)
            return

        self._DownloadFiles(res.json(), number)

    def _DownloadFiles(self, jsonfile, number_of_files):
        image_links = self._getImages(jsonfile, number_of_files)

        if not self.createFolder():
            print("Error creating folder")
            return

        index = 0 #used to name the files
        for image_link in image_links:
            image_link = image_link.replace('amp;', '')
            f = _requests.get(image_link)

            if f.status_code==200:
                media_file = open(f'{_os.getcwd()}/red_media/{index}.jpg', 'wb')

                for chunk in f.iter_content(100000):
                    media_file.write(chunk)
                media_file.close()
                print("Downloaded")
                index+=1
        print("Download complete")
        global flag
        flag=1




    def _getImages(self, jsonfile, number_of_files):

        images = [] #contains links of images
        for index in range(number_of_files):
            try:
                images.append(jsonfile['data']['children'][index]['data']['preview']['images'][0]['source']['url'])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        return images

    @staticmethod
    def createFolder():
        try:
            if not _os.path.exists(f'{_os.getcwd()}\\red_media'):
                _os.mkdir(f'{_os.getcwd()}\\red_media')
                return True
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
```

Things I would like to know:

- Is there anything that I can do to improve the performance of the code
- What can I do to improve the code styling. I have tried to follow the PEP standards as much as I could.
- Anything else to improve the code.

Answer (score 5):

A few suggestions for general code quality:

- If your class only does one thing and it doesn't store any values, it should be a function. `Redpy` only downloads images from reddit and stores values to achieve exactly this, which you could do in a function. Using a class can have unforeseen consequences.
- Choose descriptive names for variables and functions. `_getImages` does not actually get the images, it returns a list of links of images. In this method, you have `images = [] #contains links of images`. The comment could have been avoided if you would have chosen `image_links` as name.
- If you split your code up into methods or functions, everything belonging to one task should be inside it. The removal of `'amp;'` in every `image_link` does not belong in `_DownloadFiles`, it should be in `_getImages`. `download` gets unnecessarily separated into `_DownloadFiles` and `_DownloadFiles` doesn't generally download files, but it could if some of its functionality got relocated elsewhere.
- Clean up your code: there are unnecessary line breaks after `_DownloadFiles` and a redundant `return True` in `createFolder`.
- Don't catch general Exceptions, be more specific. In `_getImages`, you should just look out for `KeyError`s. Exceptions in `request.get` on the other hand are not handled although they possibly should be.
- The pattern of looping over a list with a counter (`index` in your code) in `_DownloadFiles` can be simplified with [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).
- When working with files, it is more elegant to use a [context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html).

Possible bugs:

- `subreddit.strip('/')` just returns a new string that you would have to assign to a new variable. In your code, the value of `subreddit` remains unchanged.
- `self.user` gets updated every time `download` is called. If this happens multiple  times, `self.user` becomes a dict encapsulating a dict encapsulated a dict...
- If something goes wrong when extracting links in `_getImages`, less links than expected get returned.
- If your folder already contains images, they will be overwritten.

Concerning PEP8:

- A few of your lines are longer than 80 characters. Try to split them up, either by implementing the same logic over multiple lines or by [breaking the line up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python).
- In PEP8, functions and methods are in [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Nit-picky stuff:

- You could just use an empty string as default argument for `sort_option`. Strings are immutable, so you don't have the problem of [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).
- I don't see why you would import `requests as _requests` and `os as _os`
- There is no need to construct an absolute file path. `f'{_os.getcwd()}/red_media/{index}.jpg'` could become `f'red_media/{index}.jpg'`

---

Here is my attempt at solving this problem:

```
import requests
import os


def get_image_links(json, N):
    '''returs a list of the first <N> links to reddit images found in <json>'''
    try:
        children = json['data']['children']
    except KeyError:
        return []

    # append links from children until N are found
    image_links = []
    for child in children:
        try:
            image_link = child['data']['preview']['images'][0]['source']['url']
        except KeyError:
            continue

        image_link = image_link.replace('amp;', '')
        image_links.append(image_link)

        if len(image_links)==N:
            break

    return image_links

def download_files(file_links, folder_name='data', file_extension='jpeg'):
    '''downloads files from <file_links> into subfolder ./<folder_name>/'''

    # create subfolder if it does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)

    # download files
    for i, file_link in enumerate(file_links):
        try:
            res = requests.get(file_link)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            print(f"Unable to download {file_link}")
            continue
        if not res.ok:
            print(f"Error {res.status_code} when requesting {file_link}")
            continue

        file_path = os.path.join(folder_name, f'{i}.{file_extension}')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
                file.write(chunk)

def download_reddit_images(user, subreddit, N=5, sort_by='',
                           folder_name='red_media'):
    '''
    downloads the first <N> images of <subreddit> sorted by <sort_by>
    (''/'new'/'hot'/'top') into subfolder ./<folder_name>/
    '''

    json_url = ('https://www.reddit.com/r/' + subreddit.strip('/') + '/'
                + sort_by + '.json')

    try:
        res = requests.get(json_url, headers={'user-agent':user})
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        print(f"Unable to get {json_url}")
        return

    if not res.ok:
        print(f"Error {res.status_code} when requesting {json_url}")
        return

    image_links = get_image_links(res.json(), N)
    if not len(image_links):
        print("Unable to find any images")
        return

    download_files(image_links, folder_name=folder_name, file_extension='jpeg')


if __name__=='__main__':
    download_reddit_images('', 'all')
```

The problem of overwriting existing images persists. A solution would be to use the original filename from reddit that is included in the url.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your answer was the most comprehensive and detailed analysis of the code. I had updated the code after following some PEP 8 guidelines. Here it is https://github.com/prashantsengar/RedPy ...
I will update the code again based on your suggestions. 
I have a question though, how can using a class have unforeseen consequences. I want to know more about it. And thanks again for your valuable input

Comment: By unforeseen consequences I meant bugs like the one with `self.user`, since you wouldn't expect the code execution to be dependant on previous calls. The problem with using a class here is that it makes the code more complex than it has to be, while a function would work just fine. With the class, it also takes more lines to access the functionality of your code, since you have to create a `Redpy` object and then call `download`, whereas the only thing you gain is not having to enter `user` multiple times. For more information see [this talk](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0).

Comment: Thanks again for explaining so nicely @reeetooo

Comment: I would probably make a `download_file` function that just downloads a file to a destination and do the iterating over the links directly in `download_reddit_images`. But otherwise a very nice first review, welcome to Code Review!